# MS Chart series even if I assign integer vallues to xaxis values, X values always zero

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple Windows Forms and I am using MS chart to plot line chart.Below is the code I am using to plot the chart.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Y"));

    for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["X"] = i*2;
        dr["Y"] = i * i;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "X";
    chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Y";
    chart1.DataSource = dt;
    chart1.DataBind();

     DataPointCollection dpc = chart1.Series[0].Points;      

}
```

This works as expected and the graph displays with the correct X an Y values. However, if I later try look up values in the series (to get the Y value associated with an X position on the chart), I discover that all the DataPoints in the series Points collection have X=0 (the Y values are OK).

I am assigning inter value only to X values not string but still getting 0 only for x values

This very strange since the data is actually plotted with the correct X axis values. Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: @taw, x values are interger only, I am assigning interger only to datatable row.

Comment: @taw please remove duplicate mark. THis question is not duplicate. the links you suggested didn't answer my question. Since you marked duplicate I couldn't post any new question also.

Comment: You are creating the DataTable.Column in the __wrong__ way. The [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) only creates __string__ columns. You need to create some number type columns like so: `dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X", typeof(int)));`. I suggest getting it right for the y column as well. Note that the chart will try convert y-values to double but not x-values, as you can read in my links..

Comment: @Taw - I could not post new questions since you marked this question as duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate, see my above comment!

Comment: @Taw, I am new to C#, I don't know that datatable.colums are by default strings

Comment: I was surprised as well as I always tell it the types I need. Btw: You shouldn't be banned from posting a new question just because of a duplicate. If that should be the case do contact a moderator for advice!